# Deny Read-Only Users to see DDL of a Stored Procedure MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, procedure

Several read-only users have Management Studio and run their own queries, which is not a problem. However, I would like to protect the code of the Stored Procedures and views so that people can't see the code behind them by right clicking on the object and selecting Script Procedure As>Create to>New Query Window.

I tried adding WITH ENCRYPTION, but this block even the DBOs from seeing the code. So that is not a good solution.

Is there any other way that I could accomplish this?

Comment: Why do these users have SSMS installed in the first place???

Comment: I wish it wasn't the case, but it is a very fast pacing project and people kind of figure things out as they go. We do create reporting services reports for most people, but there are about 10 users who think are "technical enough" to write their own queries. I don't like it that they do and this is the reason why I want to stop them from seeing the code.

Comment: I think if you deny permission to execute sp_helptext they won't be able to do this anymore. Can't double check this at the moment.

Comment: "DENY VIEW DEFINITION" should have worked. I'm assuming that you are a dbo in the database in question. Impersonate them and see what sys.user_token and sys.login_token say about them. I suspect the former may show them as in the db_owner role or the latter may show sysadmin…

Comment: Yes, thank you everyone, DENY VIEW DEFINITION ON [MY_SP_NAME] TO PUBLIC solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to deny VIEW DEFINITION permission. The following post goes into detail on this feature.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1828/options-for-hiding-sql-server-code/

See section "ALTERNATE TO USING WITH ENCRYPTION CLAUSE".